# Documenting a duck-typed parameter in numpydoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, duck-typing, numpydoc

According to the convention in [guide to numpy/scipy documentation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt) function parameters should be documented in the following way:

```
def foo(x):
    """" This function does nothing

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : type
       Description of parameter `x`.
    """"
    pass
```

This is straightforward if type is a distinct type such as *int* or *str*.

Now I want the parameter to be an instance of *BaseClass* or any object that exposes the same interface (such as a class derived from *BaseClass*). Is there a convention how to concisely document that parameter *x* should expose a certain interface (by derivation or duck-typing)?

Comment: Maybe "BaseClass-like object", in analogy with "file-like object"? NumPy uses "array-like" a lot for arrays or objects convertible to array, but that's slightly different; lists of lists don't expose the interface of an array.

Comment: That's how I currently do it. However, I am not entirely happy with that approach because Class-like feels rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you described is pretty much the standard one.

Another approach is to use abstract base classes to define the specific methods that must be implemented and then specify that as the type as suggested on [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059800/).